# Retrieving data contained in a List using a controller causes an error

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am very new to Blazor and web applications. I have been stuck on this error, cannot seem to figure out what is causing this. I feel it's the controller but I also can't seem to figure out why.

### Todo.razor

```
@inject HttpClient http;
@inject BlazorTodoApp.Client.Services.ITodoItemService todoItemService

<h3> Todo (@todos.Count()) </h3>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="@todo.isDone" />
            <input @bind="@todo.Title" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="something todo" @bind="newTodo" />
<button @onclick="AddTodo"> Add Todo</button>


@code {

private List<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();
private string newTodo;

private void AddTodo()
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo)) {
        todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
        newTodo = string.Empty;
    }
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        todos = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<TodoItem>>("api/TodoItems");
    }
    catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
    {
        exception.Redirect();
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class TodoItemsController : ControllerBase
{

    public List<TodoItem> todoPosts { get; set; } = new List<TodoItem>()
    {
        new TodoItem {Id = 1, Title = "number 11:",  isDone = false},
        new TodoItem {Id = 2, Title = "number 21:",  isDone = false}
    };

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<TodoItem>> GetItems()
    {

        return Ok(todoPosts);
    }
}
```

**Error**
[image]

Clicking on the HTTP request link shows me my data but it does not show up as coded in the HTML portion of the page
[image]

**HTML**
[image]

Adjusted the to-do title to have size of the "todos" list appear next to it and it remains at 0 for some reason.
[image]

**Requested classes**

### Program.cs [Client]

```
 public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorTodoApp.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

        // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BlazorTodoApp.ServerAPI"));
        //builder.Services.AddScoped<ITodoItemService, TodoItemService>();
        builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://api.id.uri/access_as_user");
        });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

### Startup.cs [Server]

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: seems you did not initialize HttpClient object

Comment: The error says `TodoItemService.cs:line 30`, but you show us only 15 lines of it. What is on line 30?

Comment: Line 30: return await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<TodoItem>>("api/TodoItems");. I removed some methods above it so it's clearer in the post which reduced the amount of lines.

Comment: Your controller looks fine. You're initializing todoPosts, so that wouldn't be the "object reference not set to an instance of an object." Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the constructor of your TodoItemService class to make sure http (not _http) you've properly registered the service in Startup.cs and that it's not null. There's a lot that could be the source of your problem in Todo.razor. Could be that you're app is incurring a null todo item in your foreach loop. What does your code for newTodo, which you have bound, and AddTodo look like? All in all, we need a lot more info to help.

Comment: The fact that you get a count from the call to @todos.Count() tell us your list of todos is not null. Otherwise, the UI wouldn't render the default page in your screenshot.

Comment: Now I doubt that there is a null todo in your foreach loop because you showed us that your HTTP GET to your controller's single endpoint does not contain null data (good troubleshooting there btw). 

What does newTodo and AddTodo() look like?

Comment: I have updated the post to show the AddTodo() those fields and methods work fine, the problem is not being able to retrieve data from the controller

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint here to make sure http isn't null?

public TodoItemService(HttpClient http)
{    <--- breakpoint here
        _http = http;
}

Comment: The code you have posted looks largely Ok. The error seems to happen in the AuthorizationMessageHandler so show all code related to the configuration of the HttpClient.  The Startup class and/or Program.cs

Comment: I have updated the post to show startup and program classes. I have also removed the service class and injected http into the razor file to make http requests with the controller. This did not resolve the issue but hopefully makes it easier to understand.

Comment: A side issue, but you have a `ITodoItemService` which in the UI doesn't seem to do a lot. From a design perspective, all the data and data access should be in there, not in the UI.  Stuff like getting the data via the HttpClient and `List<TodoItem> todos`.  Seems pedantic, but without good design principles things can soon get very out of control.

Comment: The Startup code all looks like standard template stuff. Doublecheck your `"AzureAD"` configurations (2x). Do you have other means to verify your App registration etc ?

Comment: Also, add any [Attributes] you have on top of the Controller class. The snippet with the Browser already shows they are correct but lets strike them as a possible cause.

Comment: I have added the [Attributes] to the controller. I was asked to make a blazor web assembly project with identify enabled and to import Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;

Answer (score 0):

Here's some hints to try:

1. Confirm the controller is getting hit and refactor the code to make sure it's returning what you expect.
2. Replace the `GetFromJsonAsync` with `GetAsync` and see what response you get back.  Check the response and the object returned.

Everyone is making educated guesses. You need to establish which object reference is not set to an instance by stepping through the code line-by-line in debug mode.

Answer (score -1):

From the error message it looks like the ITodoItemService needs to be correctly injected into the system.

Comment: Negative, you would get a developer error page stating the service is missing.